# Tests not run on aspnet core 3.0 test project compiled by Azure Devops

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, vstest

I have the following repository
https://github.com/Mech0z/Foosball
Where I have the following project file I would like the test step in pipelines to run

https://github.com/Mech0z/Foosball/blob/master/Integrationstest/Integrationstest.csproj

It has the following packages

```
<PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.12.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.15.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.3.0" />
```

And my yaml file is like this

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*/Integrationstest.csproj'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

But when it runs I get

> Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not
>   match framework/platform settings. Integrationstest.dll is built for
>   Framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0 and Platform AnyCPU.

How do I change the .NET framework in my yaml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the VSTest task, use the DotNetCore task to run your tests e.g.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: "test"
      projects: "**/*/Integrationstest.csproj"
    displayName: Run the server-side tests
```

Comment: So the yaml it created for me is pretty useless for aspnet core projects?
https://github.com/Mech0z/Foosball/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml I would presume I should also use DotNetCoreCLI instead of task: VSBuild@1

Comment: Yes, that yml file is not suitable for .NET Core projects.

Comment: also this could be an issue because usually you would do a build and publish in the pipeline and do the test after the release of the app is done (unless you are unit testing and not UI testing). the dotnet test : builds, restores and runs the project. It cannot be done during the release but only in the pipeline itself which is a problem for UI testing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Azure DevOps and I had to add this to `Other Console Options`:

`/Framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1`

and specify the concrete .dll where tests are compiled. It was UnitTests.dll in my case, so in `Test files` I wrote:

`**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\UnitTests.dll`

and it fixed the issue.

Comment: I added this as well in the release but I compiled dlls in the build pipeline and it did not work. Could you extend a bit on your tasks and share a bit more ? I am having issues.